# What's the best policy to follow with answers to "debug my code" questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Every single day, I see a few questions with the same format: something generic, along the lines of *"It doesn't work"*, followed by a poorly formatted piece of source code with macroscopic issues, if not syntax errors. No hints at what the problem might be, no proof of effort being shown.

A row of downvotes and *"use a debugger"*, *"what have you tried so far?"*, *"learn C/C++/whatever and it will be crystal clear"* comments follows, until someone posts an answer, pointing out the obvious. Many of these questions are closed and eventually deleted, but the OP gets the answer.

My opinion is that answering these questions is detrimental to the community, since it encourage help vampires. It's detrimental to the OPs too, as they won't learn to solve their problems, which is an essential task for a programmer (well, not only for a programmer). Nothing makes you learn something like spending two hours debugging your code. Maybe some hints by more experienced programmers might help, but you can use the chat for that.

Well, if I see a complete (not a hint) answer, I often leave a comment for author, telling not to encourage this kind of behavior. Until a high-rep user (around 5000 points) replied saying that since the answer was that easy and he knew it, he saw absolutely no problem with posting it.

I know it's quite easy to answer these questions, but that's not the point. Anyway his remark made me question my own opinion. So, what would be the best course of action?

1. ignoring them?
2. possibly leaving hints in the comments?
3. answering by giving some hints?
4. answering with a complete answer?
5. marking as duplicate of reference questions pertaining the specific topic (like allocating huge arrays on the heap, not freeing `malloc`ed memory etc.)? These questions are quite unique, but the issues with code are more or less the same.
6. something else?

And, more importantly, **was the 5000-point user behaviour acceptable? Is the behaviour of people answering these questions acceptable? Is it OK to tell them not to encourage help vampires?**

Comment: Close the question as "off-topic > 'why won't it work?'". You have the judge the answers on their own merits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think this is a duplicate, since I am concerned with people feeding help vampires who post code with macroscopic issues, not with too specific debugging issues. I completely agree with closing them, but I would like to know if the community finds acceptable to answer these questions and, if yes, to what extent.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: the other post outlines what is acceptable. If the 'fix my code' question doesn't meet those criteria, it is not acceptable and should just be closed.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: closing a question also prevents answers being added; the faster such questions are closed, the fewer answers can be given.

Comment: VTC as unclear, downvote, move on.  Five seconds and done.

Comment: 5000 is not high-rep. did you mean 50000?

Comment: I don't even bother with the downvote.  Most of 'em are 'member for today' homework bloodsuckers.

Comment: @MartinJames: As long as they are already decently negative so they will be cleaned up...

Comment: @MartinJames 2 effects of downvotes. First, I can't see close votes without opening questions, but I can see a negative score right away. If I see a question with a negative score that I would not have *otherwise* looked at, I may look at it to see if it needs closing. The more negative (and not yet closed), the more likely I'll look. (Yep, I look at trash on purpose.) Second, the OP may get the hint. There's a sting to a downvote (for folks with rep > 1) that a v-t-c does not carry. I've had two just yesterday that were taken care of like that (self-delete). Please downvote.

Comment: We used to close those questions as "Too localized" since they only ever help one user.  No longer available, we now pick the exact opposite.

Comment: I am sorry most of you missed the point of the question, perhaps the edit will make things clearer but feel free to further edit.

I will stress again that I am not concerned with the questions themselves (I completely agree with closing them), rather with people answering these questions. Just to rephrase the question: was the 5000-point user behaviour acceptable? Is the behaviour of people answering these questions acceptable? Is it OK to tell them not to encourage help vampires?

Comment: @Deduplicator at 5000 rep points you have earned most privileges, apart from access to moderator tools, which makes you a valuable member of the community. 50000+ users are part of a tiny, tiny élite, so unless you consider 10000+ users as low-rep...

Answer (score 5):

In general, questions like this are **Too Broad.** If it doesn't seem possible to answer their question with a reasonably small amount of code and prose, vote to close accordingly.

If it applies, you can also use

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Note that "demonstration of effort" is not a valid metric to close, and never was.

Comment: Bless you for that last line. That's something people are quick to forget.

Comment: Please see my edit to the question.